# How to run SASM Assembly IDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, scripts

I have downloaded SASM Assembly IDE for Ubuntu from here:

https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries/home:Dman95/SASM?repository=xUbuntu_15.04

but after extracting I cannot see any script which I should use to launch the program?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total amateur at this but hang with me.  I was able to download the sasm_3.5.1_amd64.deb
file from the link you gave above.  If you double-click on this .deb file it opens up Ubuntu software center and the software center performs the installation.

I changed your link from Ubuntu_15.04 to Ubuntu_14.04 as that is what I am running.

To download the .deb file, go to the link you gave.  Click on the line at the top that says "State of Repository xUbuntu_15.04 for home:Dman95 / SASM".
This will take you to another page that has the .deb file you need to download and you'll be able to run this with Ubuntu software center.

Even though my laptop is using an intel core i7 I got a 
"Cannot install 'gcc-multilib:i386'
error message trying to install the i386.deb file.
I had had install the AMD .deb file to make it work.   I was then able to run it and then build and run NASMHello.asm.  It appears to work ok.  Hope this helps.